# Comparing and displaying hash values

Tags: linux, perl, shell, hash, scripting

I am able to print all of the lines from `/etc/passwd` by `UID` and username.

I would like to compare the values of `UID` and display corresponding usernames by `<150` and `>150`.

this is my while loop and count

```
while(<PASSWD>){
    chomp;
    my @f = split /:/;
    sort @f;
    @{$passwd{$f[3]}}=@f;
    print @f[3 , 0], "\n";
}

my $count = keys(%passwd);
print $count, "\n";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort @f` does nothing - `sort` returns the list sorted, but does not change it in place. If you added `use warnings;` to your programme, Perl would tell you.

This is how I would do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $PASSWD, '<', '/etc/passwd' or die $!;

my %passwd;
while (<$PASSWD>) {
    chomp;
    my @f = split /:/;
    @{ $passwd{ $f[3] } } = @f;
 }

my $reported = 0;
for my $k (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %passwd) {
    if ($k > 150 and not $reported) {
        $reported = print "Over 150\n";
    }
    print "$k\n";
}
```

You can also `grep` the keys for the small ones:

```
my @under150 = grep $_ < 150, keys %passwd;
print $_->[0], "\n" for @passwd{ @under150 };
```

Comment: historical note: http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2004/06/msg92477.html